# http2 post request with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, python-requests, http2

I am trying to form a post request with python; however, I'm running into problems because the python request library does not support the format of these request headers:

:authority:
:method:
:path:
:scheme:

I have tried a bunch of different things but nothing seems to work. Are there any good python libraries out there for performing post requests with http2?

Note: I have tried the hyper library, but it has very little documentation and I could not figure out how to use it.

This is an example of the request headers from the chrome dev tool.

:authority: www.nakedcph.com

:method: POST

:path: /cart/process

:scheme: https

accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br

accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6

cache-control: max-age=0

content-length: 250

content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

cookie: __cfduid=d2d9e8bb674df8622efa8dffc81d38f301489014617; png.state=jNMd1SDYzyjF0baeJz4wTQNxzFm06+wBrIwNuuAnlvknAd/LX67aaSvFOL8YfeALxD/RPXoxufarQcUKpt8cEsgUP3RfZk/5St8zfWchoVaORX+o; AntiCsrfToken=55a7751f0ac743c69e35484870903b9e; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1848414576.1489014618

origin: https://www.nakedcph.com

referer: https://www.nakedcph.com/cart/view

upgrade-insecure-requests: 1

user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36

Comment: Can you provide the actual headers, in a curl format, or copied from Chrome, or any actual sample?

Comment: In python requests you can simply provide a dictionary of the different headers.  ie headers = {':authority': 'someauthority', ':method:': 'somemethod} then headers=headers.

Comment: @Artagel Yes that is how I am formatting my headers, but the requests library recognizes a header name with a colon in front as invalid syntax. Requests will throw an error if you try to use a header with the leading colon. (note the second colon is not actually part of the header name, just an indication of where the header data actually starts)